# isolate license plate numbers opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to know how I can process an image of a License plate so I can use this output with an OCR Library like Tesseract.
Here you can see an example of the image i'm trying to process
http://s13.postimage.org/knf9zvxee/vaflo.jpg

What I am trying to get in this case is just the String "KND 486".
So I need to isolate this from everything. You might notice that the string that I am looking for is the biggest one, and as it is a License plate from Argentina, it will always appear 3 letters and then 3 numbers.

As you can see, I've tried to binarize the original picture, but I am not getting the results I expected. 
Does anyone knows what else should I do?

Comment: What are the results you expect? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I've edited my question. Please let me know if any other information would be useful. I am know to OpenCV, so I know maybe the question is to broad.

Comment: @blas: Your image is actually pretty clean. You could use blob detection and a simple SVM to classify those letters.

Comment: Can you tell me how? I am totally new at Open CV

Comment: You may consider a simple algorithm such as shape matching. I hope this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785664/finding-shapes-in-an-image-using-opencv helps.